# Unable to load one or more of the requested types c# Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, types

i've got a project where i search on another project bin directory on the purpose of write all the methods from each assembly:

```
public static List<ManagerMethodDescr> getManagerMethodDescr(string nomeClasse)
    {
        DirectoryInfo inf = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\NETASUITE\Backend\NETASIAL\Business\Managers.Common\bin");
        FileInfo[] fileDll = inf.GetFiles("*.dll");

        List<ManagerMethodDescr> ManagerDesc = new List<ManagerMethodDescr>();

        foreach (FileInfo fi in fileDll)
        {
            Assembly newAss = Assembly.LoadFile(fi.FullName);
            try
            {
                foreach (Type tipo in newAss.GetTypes())
                {
                    if (tipo.Name == nomeClasse)
                    {
                        MethodInfo[] mis = tipo.GetMethods();
                        foreach (MethodInfo mi in mis)
                        {
                            IEnumerable<CustomAttributeData> ieC = mi.CustomAttributes;
                            string arg = "";
                            if (ieC.Count() > 0)
                            {
                                if (ieC.ElementAt(0).ConstructorArguments.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    arg = ieC.ElementAt(0).ConstructorArguments[0].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                }
                            }
                            if (mi.IsPublic && arg == "Interfaccia")
                            {
                                MethodAttributes ma = mi.Attributes;
                                string ritorno = mi.ReturnType.Name.ToString();
                                string name = mi.Name;
                                ParameterInfo[] pi = mi.GetParameters();
                                List<string[]> Param = new List<string[]>();
                                foreach (ParameterInfo ppi in pi)
                                {
                                    Param.Add(new string[] { ppi.Name, ppi.ParameterType.Name.ToString() });
                                }
                                ManagerDesc.Add(new ManagerMethodDescr(ritorno, name, Param, mi.ReturnType.Namespace));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
            {
             IEnumerable<Type> iet=   e.Types.Where(t => t != null);


            }

        }
        return ManagerDesc;
    }
```

for some assembly i get error like "Could not load type 'NETA.SUITE.SIAL.Tipi.Base.SialBaseType' from assembly 'NETA.SUITE.SIAL.Tipi.Base" **(the exception is given when i do newAss.GetTypes() )** even if the references are well written and all set to copy local true...i can't get rid of it...i tryied with a simple project i made for example purpose and it worked...

Comment: I would probably refrain from calling your variable `newAss`

Comment: you are probably right but not all developer are American or English, so for us italian developer newAss means nothing...probably before writing here i should have changed the name ;)